# Pull to refresh in Titanium for Android

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

How to pull to refresh?

In Titanium appcelerator I need to show a list of content in tableview. If I pull the view it needs to update. In iPhone I complete but in Android it won't work. Please any one help to solve this problem in Android.

My Android code:-

```
tableView.addEventListener('scroll',function(e)
{
   var offset = e.contentOffset.y;
   if (offset < -65.0 && !pulling && !reloading)
   {
       var t = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
       t = t.rotate(-180);
       pulling = true;
       arrow.animate({transform:t,duration:180});
       statusLabel.text = "Release to refresh...";
   }
   else if((offset > -65.0 && offset < 0 ) && pulling && !reloading)
   {
       pulling = false;
       var t = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
       arrow.animate({transform:t,duration:180});
       statusLabel.text = "Pull down to refresh...";
   }    
});

tableView.addEventListener('dragEnd', function(e)
{

   if(pulling && !reloading)
   {
       reloading = true;
       pulling = false;
       arrow.hide();
       actInd.show();
       statusLabel.text = "Reloading...";
       tableView.setContentInsets({top:60},{animated:true});
       tableView.scrollToTop(-60,true);
       arrow.transform=Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
       beginReloading();
   }
});
```

Comment: Hey have figured this out ??

Answer (score 1):

Titanium now supports pull to refresh for BOTH Android (> v6.2.0) and iOS (>3.2.0) with a Titanium.UI.TableView, Titanium.UI.ListView or Titanium.UI.ScrollView object.

See the docs:

- https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView
- https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.RefreshControl

Sample code taken from the docs:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    fullscreen:true
});
var counter = 0;

function genData() {
    var data = [];
    for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        data.push({properties:{title:'ROW '+(counter+i)}})
    }
    counter += 3;
    return data;
}

var section = Ti.UI.createListSection();
section.setItems(genData());

var control = Ti.UI.createRefreshControl({
    tintColor:'red'
})

var listView = Ti.UI.createListView({
    sections:[section],
    refreshControl:control
});

control.addEventListener('refreshstart',function(e){
    Ti.API.info('refreshstart');
    setTimeout(function(){
        Ti.API.debug('Timeout');
        section.appendItems(genData());
        control.endRefreshing();
    }, 2000);
})

win.add(listView);
win.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this just the IOS code form the Kitchen Sink example?

There are a couple of attempts at getting this working on Android, though I haven't confirmed that any of them work as expected.  From what I understand, the problem is that you can't get the offset the same way in Android as in IOS.

A quick Google search turned up this link, which was referenced from the official Appcelerator forums.
https://gist.github.com/903895

Comment: I just tried that gist and realized that it's not efficient. It will probably do the trick for small lists of data but one of the robust features of the list component in iOS and Android is that they recycle rows when scrolling occurs such that no more than aprox the number of rows in view + 1 are ever rendered at a time. So, whether you have 50 or 1000 rows, the speed is the same. The technique in this Gist requires the table to be the height of all its rows and so no recycling will occur and it will be slow (especially with remote image urls) and require more ram.

Comment: What I'm hoping to have time to try and what I think could work pretty well is to create a Packaged module for Titanium from this Java project: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Comment: The answer was merely to point the original poster in a direction.  It wasn't to do the work for the original poster nor every to provide the most efficient solution.  Are you the original poster?  How many accounts are you using?